# Mapping back Viewmodels to Models

Tags: c#, mapping, viewmodel, cqrs

In my N-Layered DDD architectured, all my `ViewModel` classes in application layer, implement following interface:

```
public interface IViewModel
{
    ModelEntitySuperType ToModel();
}
```

So each `ViewModel` knows how to map back to the `Domain Object`(by implementing the `ToModel()` method).

**[Updated]**

Also I used `CQRS` pattern in my Application layer, so I defined the following generic abstract class for implementing `Update` command, you can see the usage of `ToModel()` method in followiing class(`Handle` method):

```
public abstract class UpdateCommandHandler<TCommandParameter, TViewModel, TEntity> : ICommandHandler<TCommandParameter>
    where TCommandParameter : UpdateCommandParameter<TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : class, IViewModel, new()
    where TEntity : ModelEntitySuperType, IAggregateRoot, new()
{
    private readonly IRepository<TEntity> _repository;

    public string Code { get; set; }

    protected UpdateCommandHandler(IRepository<TEntity> repository, string commandCode)
    {
        Code = commandCode;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommandParameter commandParameter)
    {
        var viewModel = commandParameter.ViewModelEntity;
        var entity = viewModel.ToModel() as TEntity;
        _repository.Update(entity);
    }

}
```

Is it a correct way, that I put mapping logic into `ViewModel` objects?
What is better way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I have mapping logic in layer which does mapping. Thus I keep both entities and view models unaware of each other and they have single responsibility. Responsibility of mapping between data types goes to mapping library (e.g. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)) or to extension methods.

E.g. if you want to convert `Person` entity to `PersonViewModel`, then with AutoMapper it will look like

```
 var viewModel = Mapper.Map<PersonViewModel>(person);
```

Or you can have extension method

```
 public static PersonViewModel ToViewModel(this Person person)
 {
     // create view model and map its properties manually
 }
```

Usage will look like your current code, except you don't need to cast `ModelEntitySuperType` to `PersonViewModel`:

```
 var viewModel = person.ToViewModel();
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I updated the question. If I want to use Auto-mapper to mapping, should I replace `var entity = viewModel.ToModel() as TEntity;` to `var entity = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ModelEntitySuperType>(viewModel) as TEntity;`? Is it correct that I used `Automapper` directly in my code or Should I define an IObjectMapper interface and inject it to my CommandHandler? could you please guide me with code?

Comment: @Masoud if you have mapping from TypeA to TypeB configured in AutoMapper, then you can create `UpdateCommandHandler<TParameter, TypeA, TypeB>` and map types with `Mapper.Map<TypeB>(instanceOfTypeA)`

Comment: But I don't want to change the `UpdateCommandHandler<TCommandParameter, TViewModel, TEntity>` definition. because if I change it to what you said, I have to create separate `UpdateCommandHandler` classes for each Entity Type. E.g `UpdateCommandHandler<TCommandParameter,CustomerView,Customer>` , ... . so with current defenition of `UpdateCommandHandler<TCommandParameter,TViewModel,TEntity>` should I inject something like IObjectMapper to my commandhandler or directly use the Automaper in `Handle` method?

Comment: @Masoud sorry, I never said to change definition of UpdateCommandHandler